# Tokyo Stock Exchange Historical Data

Tags: data-request, finance, japan

How can I fetch/retrieve or get Tokyo stock exchange data beginning the year 2001?
It does not have to thru code but can be a simple download or few lines of code in R or Python.
It has to be free and can be in any format.

Please tell me the procedure or the website to get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Quandl has open data from the Nikkei stock exchange, which is I guess what you mean.

https://www.quandl.com/data/NIKKEI-Nikkei

[Python Package](https://www.quandl.com/data/NIKKEI-Nikkei/usage/quickstart/python)

[R Package](https://www.quandl.com/data/NIKKEI-Nikkei/usage/quickstart/r)

Comment: Not really; I am looking for a daily average or closing price of top 50 tickers on Tokyo stock exchange.

Comment: When I clicked on your link, it does not provide data on any ticker.

Comment: please add some example company tickers to your question